# How do I find the starting number from the sequence with the Max Value

Tags: c++, vector, indexing, collatz

In my code I computed the Collaz sequences of the range from start to end. I ran the code and everything prints correctly except for the starting element of the sequence with the greatest value. I debugged and saw that my max is correct however I end up printing the end for the starting number of the sequence with the greastest value. I tried resetting i and I also tried to see if there was an issue with my if statement

Ideally it should look like this once correct 
Example Program:

Start: 1

End: 6

Max Value: 16 (3)

Here is my code

```
int main()
{
  // This declare the int start and end and prints them to the user as well as takes what the user gives 
  int start, end;
  std::cout << "Start: ";
  std::cin >> start;
  std::cout << "End: ";
  std::cin >> end;

  // Here a vector called sequences is created. This holds a Collatz Sequences
  std::vector<CollatzSequence> sequences;
  int i = start;
  while (i <= end)
  {
    sequences.push_back(CollatzSequence(i));
    i = i + 1;
  }

  {
    // A vector is made to hold the collatz sequences
    std::vector<int> maxValues;
    i = 0;
    while (i < sequences.size())
    {
      maxValues.push_back(sequences[i].getMax());
      i = i + 1;
    }
    // Here this declares varibles as intagers
    int max = maxValues[0];
    int maxIndex = 0;
    {
      // The i (index) is declare as  integer
      int i = 1;
      // While i is less then the size of the vector maxValues
      while (i < maxValues.size())
      {
        // If true (the element at maxValue is greater then the max)
        if (maxValues[i] > max)
          // max value will be that element
          max = maxValues[i];
          // maxIndex will be the idex at maxValue or address
          maxIndex = maxValues[i];
        // i is then incremented which mean it will go through the sequence at each address
        i = i + 1;
      }
      std::cout << "Max Value: " << max << " (" << sequences[maxIndex].getStart() << ")\n";
    }
  }
```

And here is where I define my functions

```
CollatzSequence::CollatzSequence(int start)
 int CollatzSequence::getMax()
{
  int max = getNumbers()[0];
  {
    for (int i = 1; i < getNumbers()[i]; i++)
      if (getNumbers()[i] > max)
        max = getNumbers()[i];
  }
  return max;
}
int CollatzSequence::getStart()
{
  int start = getNumbers()[0];
  return start;
}


std::vector<int> const & CollatzSequence::getNumbers()
{
  return numbers;
}
```

Please let me know if you see and error I don't or if I did something wrong. I tried to only post what is needed and not post 4 files. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You posted a `main` function, so start from there and post what is required to get `main` to compile, link, and run.

Comment: `// The i (index) is declare as  integer`  You also should use more meaningful variable names, not one letter names like `i`.  If you take a look at `main`, you have two `i` variables declared, with the latter stepping on the first one.  Maybe that is the issue you're having.

Comment: "// Here this declares varibles as intagers" Comments like these are useless. The only people reading your code are programmers, so there is no point in writing comments with information that any programmer can easily obtain just by reading the code. Instead, write comments to explain what your code does on a higher level, such as "this function returns the index of the maximum value in the array".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you solved the problem by yourself right now. But anyway, lets answer the question so that it is not an 0-answer count.

The bug is in that line:

```
// maxIndex will be the idex at maxValue or address
maxIndex = maxValues[i];
```

You do not store the index, but the value. And that could be a big value and hence, out of bounds.

The correct solution is:

```
// maxIndex will be the idex at maxValue or address
maxIndex = i;
```

That should work.

Just for the fun of it, I created a "more-modern-C++"-elements solution using the algorithm library. Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

// Collatz Sequence and its max value
struct CollatzSequence {

    CollatzSequence() {}

    // This will construct the collatez sequence and calculate the max value
    explicit CollatzSequence(unsigned int value); 

    // Values of the Collatz Sequence
    std::vector<unsigned int> data{};

    // The maximum value of all values of the Collatz sequence
    unsigned int maxValue{ 1U };
};

// Constructor for the Collatz Sequence. Will calculate all values of the sequence and the maxim value
CollatzSequence::CollatzSequence(unsigned int value) {

    // We calculate values as long as we did not find 1, always the last vale 
    // (There is no mathematicla evidence that this is always true)
    while (value > 1U) {

        // Store the current calculated value
        data.push_back(value);

        // Check, if this is the biggest value so far, and, if so, store it
        maxValue = std::max(value, maxValue);

        // Calculate next value in the row according to the Collatz Sequence rules
        value = ((value & 1U) == 0) ? (value >> 1U) : (3U * value + 1U);
    }
    // Always add 1 as the last element. This we do not need to calculate
    data.push_back(1U);
}

int main() {

    // Inform user to enter start end end value
    std::cout << "Calculate Collatz sequences. Please specify a range, a start and a end value:\n";

    // Read the start value and check, if this worked
    if (unsigned int rangeStart{}; std::cin >> rangeStart) {

        // Now read end value and check, if a correct range has been specified
        if (unsigned int rangeEnd{}; (std::cin >> rangeEnd) && rangeStart <= rangeEnd) {

            // Create a vector for Collatz Sequences. Allocate sufficent elements for the specified range
            std::vector<CollatzSequence> sequences(rangeEnd - rangeStart + 1);

            // Create all requested sequences
            std::generate(sequences.begin(), sequences.end(), [i = rangeStart]()mutable { return CollatzSequence(i++); });

            // Get the max element 
            std::vector<CollatzSequence>::iterator mve = max_element(sequences.begin(), sequences.end(),
                [](const CollatzSequence& cs1, const CollatzSequence& cs2) { return cs1.maxValue < cs2.maxValue; });

            // Show result to the world
            std::cout << "Max Value: " << mve->maxValue << " (" << mve->data[0] << ")\n";
        }
        else {
            std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Invalid range specified\n";
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Could not get start value for range\n ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When I changed ```maxIndex = i;``` I was able to print however this didn't print the proper sequence starting number  this printed the last sequence starting number that was iterated.